# Magento2: How to show subtotal in minicart

Tags: magento2, cart

I'm trying to show subtotal in minicart block. I've overridden minicart.phtml in my theme and added the below code:

```
<span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal_excl_tax'), blockLoader: isLoading"></span>
```

Its showing subtotal on page refresh. But when I add product in the cart the amount doesn't load by Ajax.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: subtotal is already default show in minicart.

Comment: @Rakesh thanks for your reply. please see this http://prntscr.com/cv9sqp

Comment: Show your code file

Comment: <span class="cart-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Mijn artikelen'); ?>
   <span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal_excl_tax'), blockLoader: isLoading"></span>
        </span>

Comment: I've added above code in overridden minicart.phtml. Its loading subtotal after page refresh. I wan't it should work like quantity. Means when I add product to cart it should be load via Ajax.

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Subtotal along with counter

```
<span class="counter qty empty"
      data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
    <span class="counter-number">
    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <!-- ko text: '0' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <span class="counter-label">
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <span class="counter-number" data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please help me?
I have displayed cart item custom but when I remove item not able to remove from minicart.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
<span class="counter qty subtotal empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number" data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
        </span>
```

Hope this helps;